# Use rxjava2 to loop through an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an arraylist which contains a set of objects.I would like to use rxjava so i can loop through the list in such a way that in the onSubscribe method instead of getting the entire list at once i get each list item 1 at a time

Comment: That's almost at the top of every RXJava example… try a search engine for once! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was actually Observable.fromIterable that did the trick, Observable.from returns the entire array at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on android it is recommended to use retrolambda and rxandroid too.
You can remove filter ofc.
This line: .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) is for android only too.

```
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

array.add(0);
array.add(1);
array.add(2);
array.add(5);
array.add(10);

Observable.fromIterable(array)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0)
    .subscribe(integer -> Log.e(TAG, "" + integer));
```